# Global Variable Variables in PHP7 Function?

Tags: php, migration, php-7, php-7.1

Updating php5 app for php7 and meeting this difficulty... There seems to be a global variable variable in a function used all over the place like so:

```
function verify($field) {
    global ${$field};
    $value = "";
    if (isset($field)) {
        $value = ${$field};
    } else {
        // get value...
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Now this is totally fine for php5 when we have many instances like these

```
$var = verify("field");
$var2 = verify("field2");
$var3 = verify("field3");
```

It seems, though, php7 cannot accept the tricky **${$field}** part. A lot of features of the app do not work with php7 because of this function verify() can't get the values for the variables throughout the code. Any ideas how to rewrite for php7? Have to make $var, $var2, $var3 usable in scripts. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the curly braces

```
function verify($field) {
    global $$field;
    $value = "";
    if (isset($field)) {
        $value = $$field;
    } else {
        // get value...
}
return $value;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Oddly enough that did not work. Maybe the problem resides elsewhere. Will investigate further.